# How to show the series 1/n (X_1 + ... + X_n) converges in distribution to the mean (where X_i are i.i.d random variables with finite mean)

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

One way I can think of is that by the Strong law of large numbers the series converges almost surely and then almost sure convergence implies convergence in distribution but that feels like cheating a bit so looking for a more rigorous proof.

Comment: The proof using SLLN is completely rigorous.

Answer (score 1):

A proof avoiding SLLN can be given using Chebyshev's inequality when $EX_1^{2} <\infty$: $P(|\frac {S_n} n-m| >\epsilon) \leq \frac 1 {\epsilon^{2} n^{2}} Var (S_n)=\frac 1 {\epsilon^{2} n} var(X_1) \to 0$ so we get convergence in probability.

Comment: It was not assumed that $\mathbb E[|X_1|^2]<\infty$ though.

Answer (score 0):

Look at characteristic functions: if $S_n=X_1+\ldots+X_n$ then
$$
\varphi_{S_n/n}(t)=\mathbb E\left[e^{it\frac{S_n}{n}}\right]=\mathbb E\left[e^{i\frac{t}{n}(X_1+\ldots+X_n)}\right]=\mathbb E\left[e^{i\frac{t}{n}X_1}\right]\cdot\ldots\cdot\mathbb E\left[e^{i\frac{t}{n}X_n}\right]=\left(\varphi_{X_1}\left(\frac{t}{n}\right)\right)^n.
$$ 
If $\mathbb E[|X_1|]<\infty$ then we can write Taylor series at $t=0$ 
$$
\varphi_{X_1}\left(\frac{t}{n}\right)=1+i\mathbb E[X_1]\frac{t}{n}+o\left(\frac{t}{n}\right).
$$
So 
$$
\varphi_{S_n/n}(t)=\left(1+i\mathbb E[X_1]\frac{t}{n}+o\left(\frac{t}{n}\right)\right)^n \to e^{it\mathbb E[X_1]}
$$
as $n\to\infty$ for each $t$.
The limit is the characteristic function of the degenerate r.v. $\mathbb E[X_1]$.

By Lévy’s continuity theorem, the convergence of charactristic functions implies convergence in distribution of $\frac{S_n}{n}$ to $\mathbb E[X_1]$.

Moreover, since limited distribution is degenerate, the convergence in probability holds as well.